# Outlook 2010 macros not working on Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

i have some macros that use Environ:

```
Call AddButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Change13", "CONF") ' , Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "iconSP4.bmp"
```

The problem is that i have Outlook 2010 and all works but if i transfer the VbaProject on a PC that has Outlook 2007 it will not work.

Comment: Maybe change your code not to use Environ? https://www.slipstick.com/developer/windows-environment-variables-outlook-macros/

Comment: `Environ` definitely worked before 2007 so I do not believe that is the problem.  The implication of the comment is that you are using it to access an image.  Does that image exist on the computer running Outlook 2007.

Comment: On my Windows 10/Office 2016 system there is no file named iconSP4,bmp and "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" is within \AppData\Roaming\".  I have noticed in the past that Microsoft files move between versions.  I suggest you investigate issues such as these.

Comment: Hi, the images are at the locations. But for some reason in 2010 it doesn't see it. I will try to adjust the address of the picture to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the specified file doesn't exist on the machine with Outlook 2007 installed.

In such cases I'd recommend breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring them on separate lines of code, so that you could debug the code and see intermidiate values.